# Can I do a DPO training on a synthetic dataset?

Tags: llm

I am currently following the fine-tuning methods for the Hugging Face model Zephyr 7B. They have implemented two fine-tuning methods, namely SFT and [DPO](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.18290), on a public dataset. Currently, I am fine-tuning a 7B model using SFT, which is progressing well. However, I have a question regarding whether it is acceptable to fine-tune the model on a DPO [dataset](https://huggingface.co/datasets/HuggingFaceH4/ultrafeedback_binarized) generated synthetically by GPT-3.5.

From my understanding, DPO should be trained on the answers produced by the same model. I want to confirm this and inquire if anyone has attempted such fine-tuning before.

Answer (score 1):

Using GPT-3.5-generated data for Domain-Adaptive Pretraining (DAPT) on a 7B model is an interesting idea, but it's typically best to use data generated by the same model you're fine-tuning. This ensures consistency and relevance. While there's no rule against using synthetic data from GPT-3.5, the success of such an approach would be experimental. If you decide to try it, make sure to thoroughly evaluate the quality of the synthetic data and compare the fine-tuning results with a baseline. It's also worth checking with the community to see if anyone else has shared experiences with a similar setup.